# Switch container view dynamically

Tags: objective-c

I'm using a storyboard container view. So I have a view controller containing a container view. I have a second, smaller view in the storyboard, which is embedded in that container via an embed segue. So far so good.

Now I would like to be able to switch the contents of that container view dynamically, when the user taps a button. The button will be on the main, larger, view. I have made another view controller of the same smaller size, and given it a different storyboard ID.

However, I can't work out how to code the switch. I can only create a single embed segue for that container.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to use the custom container view controller api to do the switching of the controllers. The following code shows one way to do that. In this project I had a segmented control in the main view controller (the one with the container view) that switches beetween the two controllers. initialVC is the controller that's embedded in IB, and substituteVC is the one I'm switching to. The property, container, is an IBOutlet to the container view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.initialVC = self.childViewControllers.lastObject;
    self.substituteVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Substitute"];
    self.currentVC = self.initialVC;
}

-(IBAction)switchControllers:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            if (self.currentVC == self.substituteVC) {
                [self addChildViewController:self.initialVC];
                self.initialVC.view.frame = self.container.bounds;
                [self moveToNewController:self.initialVC];
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (self.currentVC == self.initialVC) {
                [self addChildViewController:self.substituteVC];
                self.substituteVC.view.frame = self.container.bounds;
                [self moveToNewController:self.substituteVC];
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


-(void)moveToNewController:(UIViewController *) newController {
    [self.currentVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentVC toViewController:newController duration:.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:nil
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [self.currentVC removeFromParentViewController];
                                [newController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                                self.currentVC = newController;
                            }];
}
```

**After Edit:**

If you want to go to the new controller with no animation, you can do it like this (this substitutes for the code that I had under case 1).

```
[self addChildViewController:self.substituteVC];
[self.substituteVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
self.substituteVC.view.frame = self.container.bounds;
[self.container addSubview:self.substituteVC.view];
[self.currentVC removeFromParentViewController];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, that's terrific. One thing - to get the exact result I wanted (a straight swap - no animation), I changed your moveToNewController method, to duration:0 and options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone. But some of the code, including the completion block structure, seems redundant. Is there a simpler way to write the final method for a straight (non-animated) swap?

Comment: @JamesWhite, I've edited my answer to show how to do it with no animation.

Comment: This switching works great for me, but I'm switching UITableViews in and out of the container view, and the swapped-in table view isn't respecting "automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets", leading to the first couple of items in the swapped-in VC appearing under the iOS 7 title bar.

Comment: Ok, I've manually self.substituteVC.tableView.contentInset = self.currentVC.tableView.contentInset and that works.

Comment: I can't make this work for me. All it flips over are blank views?

Comment: @ronnyandre, you should post a question then with what code you're using, and what results you see.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks, but I actually made it work, so no need for a new question :)

Comment: The code in the answer called 'addSubview' on the container, but it never removes subviews. Does this mean that subviews pile up over time if you navigate a lot?

Answer (score 4):

[rdelmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16052018/97464) converted to Swift syntax

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.initialVC = self.childViewControllers.last
        self.substituteVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Substitute")
        self.currentVC = self.initialVC;

}
    @IBAction func switchControllers(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex{
            case 0:
                if (self.currentVC == self.substituteVC) {
                    self.addChildViewController(self.initialVC)
                    //self.initialVC.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds
                    moveToNewController(self.initialVC)
                }
            case 1:
                if (self.currentVC == self.initialVC) {
                    self.addChildViewController(self.substituteVC)
                    //self.substituteVC.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds
                    moveToNewController(self.substituteVC)
                }
            default:
            break;
        }
    }

    func moveToNewController(newController : UIViewController){
        self.currentVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        self.transitionFromViewController(
            self.currentVC!,
            toViewController: newController,
            duration: 0.2,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
            animations: nil,
            completion: { finished in
                self.currentVC.removeFromParentViewController()
                newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
                self.currentVC = newController
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with more than 2 child view controllers it's a good idea to store them in array. Also, you'll need to apply constraints every time you add a new subview to the container view. Here's a modified version of the accepted answer (using Swift 2 syntax):

```
import UIKit

class FooBarViewController: UIViewController
{
    // MARK: - IBOutlets

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    // MARK: - Properties

    var vcs = [UIViewController]()
    var currentVC: UIViewController!

    // MARK: - ViewController Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        vcs.append(childViewControllers.last!)
        vcs.append(storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FooViewControler"))       
        vcs.append(storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BarViewController"))
        currentVC = vcs[0]

        for vc in vcs {
            vc.view.frame = containerView.bounds
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Methods

    func switchToViewController(targetVC: UIViewController)
    {
        addChildViewController(targetVC)
        currentVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)

        transitionFromViewController(
            currentVC,
            toViewController: targetVC,
            duration: 0.0, // 0.3
            options: .TransitionNone, // .TransitionCrossDissolve,
            animations: nil,
            completion: { finished in
                self.currentVC.removeFromParentViewController()
                targetVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
                self.currentVC = targetVC
                self.applyConstraints()
        })
    }

    func applyConstraints()
    {
        let viewsDict = ["newSubview": currentVC.view]

        currentVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        containerView.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[newSubview]|",
                options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                metrics: nil,
                views: viewsDict))

        containerView.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[newSubview]|",
                options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                metrics: nil, views:
                viewsDict))
    }

    // MARK: - IBActions

    @IBAction func switchControllers(sender: UISegmentedControl)
    {
        let i = sender.selectedSegmentIndex

        if currentVC != vcs[i] {
            self.addChildViewController(vcs[i])
            switchToViewController(vcs[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding view controllers to "containerView"?