# iOS - Swapping View Controller's in a Container View and persisting the data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a container view that swaps to child view controllers. Upon swapping the view controllers though I lose the data the controller had when it is deallocated from memory.

How can I swap the child view controllers and keep the data the same way that a tab bar controller swaps them without losing deallocating data from memory?

Comment: How are you swapping the two controllers? You just need to have a property for each controller to keep them from being deallocated (and only create an instance if you don't have one already).

Comment: i used [this](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers) guide. @rdelmar

Comment: That's not going to work well then since segues always instantiate new view controllers. You need to do the switching in code, and keep a reference ( a property) to each controller. Look at my answer here for an example of how to do this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051899/switch-container-view-dynamically/16052018#16052018

Answer (score 1):

You should have an outer (root) ViewController which persists, and which owns the containerView and the cycling child viewControllers. 
So ideally this rootViewController (or some other object which outlives the individual child viewControllers eg appDelegate) would own the strong reference to the model, and the childViewControllers are only given a weak pointer to that model for their life cycle. It will be easier if these childViewControllers all inherit from some abstract superclass which has a weak property to point to this model object, so the rootViewController can just treat all the children as an instance of that superclass.

Edit/additional info....
make a new subclass of NSObject with properties for all of this data that you want to persist. Call it SomethingModel   Now remove the variables/properties for this data from the childrenViewControllers and give them a @property (weak, nonatomic) SomethingModel *modelObject   (Put this in a subclass on UIViewController, and then make your childrenViewControllers all subclasses of that...  Give your outer(root) ViewController a similar property, but make its one strong rather than weak. Then when you create a new childController you need only set its modelObject property and you're done :)

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any demos that could help me wrap my head around this?

Comment: Yes. Design patterns by the Gang of Four, an important volume to look into if you want to understand principles of object oriented programming. http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B000SEIBB8?ie=UTF8&redirectFromSS=1&pc_redir=T1&noEncodingTag=1&fp=1