# The tableview shift down a little when adding it into ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to the IOS. I'm using the segmented control to switch the views.

But the tableview ruins its position and I cannot scroll to the top of tableview when switching the segment.

The following code is how I switch the view of ViewController.

```
- (IBAction)SegmentedChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%ld", [sender selectedSegmentIndex]);

    switch ([sender selectedSegmentIndex]) {
        case 0:
            [TaskVC.view removeFromSuperview];
            if (![_TaskID isEqualToString:@"All"])
                [SpecificTaskVC.view removeFromSuperview];
            [self.view addSubview:[InspectionVC view]];
            [self didMoveToParentViewController:InspectionVC];
            break;
        case 1:
            [InspectionVC.view removeFromSuperview];
            if ([_TaskID isEqualToString:@"All"]) {
                 [self.view addSubview:[TaskVC view]];
                 [self didMoveToParentViewController:TaskVC];
                 break;
            }
            [self.view addSubview:[SpecificTaskVC view]];
            [self didMoveToParentViewController:SpecificTaskVC];
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some code on how you calculate the frame for your `TaskVC`, `SpecificTaskVC` and `InspectionVC`. And I am not sure if you have to call `didMoveToParentViewController` yourself, as far as I recall it can is called by iOS automatically.

Comment: Hi, Kie. I don't calculate the frame size for each ViewController. Thanks for your advice about `didMoveToParentViewController`. I will try it.

Comment: If an answer helps, remember to accept it (by clicking the check mark). This marks your question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is likely due to the new tableView's `contentInset` not being set.

If you want to [transition between tableViews in different view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16052018/4151918), a better way is by using a containerView.

Comment: It's a `contentInset` problem, and then I change the `contentInset`'s top value, It works!!! 
I will try your another advice about `containerView`. Thank you sooo much.