# how to fire the tabs in a custom uitab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I created a custom UITabBar, like this:

[image]

and I want when the user clicks on any tab, to open the corresponding content, (which is in both cases tableView)

i thought that i have to add two view controllers and then call them whenever a bar clicks. so i ended up like this:

[image]

then i saw my problem, i am not loading the content of the view controller **inside** but when a user clicks in my case now, a new view controller opens. what am i missing please?

Comment: To place view controllers into others, have a look at container views. For swapping them on user interaction, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051899/switch-container-view-dynamically) might help. Second answer has swift code.

Comment: @TimBodeit are you sure that that answer for uitabbar ?

Comment: No it's not. It's for a segmented control. But the concept remains the same. `tabBar(_: didSelectItem:)` in UITabBarDelegate and `selectedItem` on UITabBar might be good places to start.

Comment: @TimBodeit i tried, i can know now which item is being clicked, but i dont know how to load a view controller inside the view controller that has the UITabBar. any help pleae?

Comment: help please guys ....

Comment: someone help me please

Comment: help please guys, i'm waiting

Comment: Unfortunately I don't currently have the time to write a more detailed answer. The link in my first comment should (content-wise) include everything you need. I know that it's not the easiest topic to understand at the beginning. I suggest working through a couple tutorials to get a better understanding of what view controllers are and how they interact with one another and then having another look at that other question.